# differential $df$ of a function $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

''Explain what is the differential $df$ of a function $f(x)$ and what is the differential  of a function $f(x)$ at a point $x=a$.  give proper examples...''

This is just part of the instruction however upon searching the web for definitions of a ''differential'' I only came upon some vague definitions....anyone mind explaining this or redirect to a potent source?

Comment: Well a differential about a point can simply be stated as the limit of the following equation applied to right side as $x$ approaches $a $ : $\delta f = f'(a)(x-a) $ and then to make the left side equivalent to the right with this limit applied take the limit as $\delta f $ approaches zero to the left side. That is the general definition for single variable functions.

Comment: [The wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function) could be of interest.

Comment: There are a fair number of subtle ideas involved in these sorts of things, and a wide variety of ways of actually making them precise. Differential geometry introduces some of these in detail, but unfortunately at a level of sophistication much greater than one actually needs to be able to use these ideas.